# Who are the computer scientists(?) referenced in The Orbital Children?

Tags: the-orbital-children

At 5:47 of episode 5 of The Orbital Children (Chikyuugai Shounen Shoujo), three people are shown when Nasa Houston claims that AI were created to be gods to humanity. On the left is Alan Turing, but who are the others?
[image: Screenshot of episode 5]
My closest guesses so far are Richard Feynman and John von Neumann, but neither of them match exactly, and it seems like all of these portraits are referenced from specific photos.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very confident in this answer, but I've wasted too much time on failed reverse image searches to not at least share what I've found.

So, I think it's pretty clear that first person is Alan Turing, and this seems to be the referenced picture:

[image: Alan Turing]

Found on [Wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Alan_Turing_Aged_16.jpg).

For Richard Feynman, the second man, I've found this picture on [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Richard-Feynman):

[image: Richard Feynman]  [image: compare Richard]

The nose, eyebrows, and lines around the mouth match pretty well.

For John von Neumann, one of these pictures:

[image: John von Neumann 1]

[image: John 2]  [image]

Found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann) and [ft.com](https://www.ft.com/content/8dc791a2-bde4-4f1f-a928-bde11d67aee5)

The similarities in the eyes and ears make me think these are the same guy, even if the hair is quite different. I'm not sure how anime typically put these kinds of things in, but since even the Turing picture has differences, I'm guessing these are drawings based on the portraits.

I also looked through a lot of pictures of Charles Babbage, Claude Shannon, and John McCarthy, but gave up on finding any matches there.